# Software to upload files to Amazon S3

Tags: backup, cloud-storage, amazon

A few years ago, I used [S3 Fox](http://www.s3fox.net/) to upload files to my Amazon S3 storage. I need to use S3 again but now for work. It turned out that S3 Fox is not available anymore. Can you recommend a reliable and simple client for my desktop that could upload files to my account and allow me to browse data that I have there? Or there is no software for that and I should use command line?

Answer (score 1):

1. Cyberduck is great and it is free.

   https://cyberduck.io

   > Libre FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, S3, Azure & OpenStack Swift browser for Mac and Windows.

   However, Cyberduck has not been dependable with large file uploads to s3 for me.  5+ GB files fail to upload.
2. Cloudberry Explorer comes as freeware, and the paid version has a very good reputation.  I can vouch for small file uploads and am willing to bet that it is very good for large files too (although it seems you have get the paid version for the multipart upload).

   http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx#

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you're asking if there's any software in the world for that, looks like you need a real piece of advice here. I expect to see at lot of promotions and strongly recommend you choose wisely while googling backup companies.

I guess you search for something super easy to use and free, regarding S3Fox.

I have [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-amazon-s3-explorer-cloudfront-IAM.aspx) at home, really simple. I used freeware edition for a long time, because 1. there are most features, 2. it's free to try. Honestly, I switched to pro for $40 because of compression and encryption provided and me being anxious about it.

I advise you to try free version and see if it's simple and suitable enough for you.